# Running a PHP script with command line as if it was called by Apache

Tags: php, apache, cron, apc

I'm using PHP's APC module's user cache. I'm using a cron job to call a script that updates variables. When I run the script through a browser, everything works fine. However, it can't store nor retrieve variables when I'm running the script through command line. I recall reading somewhere that APC stores the variables in the Apache process. With command line, I am running the script directly (without Apache), so APC user cache isn't working.

I could not find a way to get APC to work with command line (`apc.enable_cli` does not work). Therefore, I want to find a way to run a PHP script through command line as if it was called by Apache. The scripts aren't located in the document root, so I can't use a local browser. How can I use the command line to make Apache run a PHP script?

My line for cron looks something like this:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: can you add some context as to what apc-cached data you want to access (a relevant code example)?

Comment: Maybe you should use `memcached` for this. Easy to install and you can simply access it by port or local unix socket. Or `redis`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running php with php-cli you will never reach the same APC cache as the one used in Apache by mod_php. This is *by design*.

When using `apc.enable_cli` you simply activate another APC cache, used for the lifetime of your script.

So APC is not the right place to store a 'variable', as it is not a shared storage like a Database or a key/value storage would be.

You have for example a very long thread on a drupal.org issue on [how to empty a drupal cache set on APC while running in cli mode](https://drupal.org/node/1565716), and this usually means a two step mode, where you store on a shared storage an instruction that the mod_php version could read later, no direct access.

I do not know any way to run mod_php in command line mode.

Comment: Will it work if I run PHP using something other than mod_php? arzzzen suggested CGI, will that (or more likely, FCGI) work?

Comment: php-fpm use an apc cache shared by all pools, but not shared with php-cli. For cgi I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use php-cgi version.
When you run php with terminal you use php cli version, but it can have another settings than php-cgi.